# How to disable carousel cycle, when user clicks indicators or carousel controls?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap ready made carousel, I want to disable the automated cycle feature when the user clicks on the indicators or controls (next/prev buttons). So, if user clicks on the 'next' button, the carousel will now be manual. Not strong in jQuery, but this was my attempt.

```
$('#myCarousel').click(function() {
    $(this).stop();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `interval` option via the carousel's `.data()` object, and set it to `false`..

```
$('#myCarousel').click(function() {
  $(this).data('carousel').options.interval=false;
});
```

**Demo: http://www.bootply.com/65091**

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 3, I'm doing something like this. Note: a large portion of my page is covered by the carousel, so I am telling it not to pause on hover (since odds are the mouse is already hovering).

To pause, when the carousel is clicked anywhere (including indicators):

```
$('#myCarousel').click(function () {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

To pause only when an indicator is clicked, it would be something like this. True for other elements as well.

```
$(".carousel-indicators").click(function () {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

Not directly in the scope of the question, but here is how I'm preventing it from pausing on mouse hover:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
        pause: "false"
});
```